# Cat herpes and behavior

Tags: virology, behavior

We have 2 cats, aptly named "Fatty" and "Tiny".

"Fatty" is a 6 year old house cat that hasn't seen the outside world in years.

"Tiny" is a cat we rescued about 45 days ago and she's roughly 2.5 months old.

Tiny came in with what looked like an eye infection, a million fleas and intestinal worms.
We kept the cats isolated until Tiny could be seen by a veterinary doctor. She had treatment to kill fleas and worms and we just washed her eye and it cleared quickly.

Soon after Fatty started to develop a cough; the doctor at the clinic said it was some cat flu, probably brought over by Tiny and she got some antibiotics.

If the flu is a virus, I question the antibiotics.. but we went through anyways.

Now we're a month and a half later and Fatty has completely lost her voice and she articulates sounds that are like 'krr'; she is unable to make any normal cat sounds anymore.

The doctor said it may be cat herpes that was introduced by Tiny; if this is the case, she'll never 'speak' again. In the meantime, Tiny is doing very well.

The most striking change is in her behavior; at first she didn't accept Tiny, now they are friends, but she has become slow, uninterested in any form of play, doesn't really purr anymore, doesn't come close to us and walks away when we pet her.

So, my question is: if she had the herpes virus, which is very common in stray cats where we live, can it have any effect on her brain that would explain a huge change in behavior? (her blood test is normal)

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear this. I hope it's just a temporary adjustment. You might have more luck with this on Pets.SE.

Comment: yes; I was a bit on the fence since it's about a specific virus.. but it's about cats :) I followed your advice and posted in Pets as well.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/17764/11132